# Web Developer curious about developing for the Android

Tags: c++, android

Hey there,
So I've been heavily focused on design/development using web technology for the last few years (php/mysql, javascript, etc), and I'm a bit hesitant to start learning C++.. At the same time, I see it as a potentially enjoyable learning experience.
To keep things brief, right now I'm developing an online app that plots out certain locations on a map, and you can sort through these locations and do a bunch of other nifty things..sorry to be vague. The point is: I don't see any real advantages of making this an actual "app" when the entire functionality of the app itself can do quite fine through the modern mobile browser..

Not to mention that, by living in a browser, it's much less proprietary
So, my question is: Is there any way to make a simple app that's basically porting the user to my site? I guess it'd be convenient that as an app, the user has a nice little icon to click on when they do need to access it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android development relies heavily on Java.  So you are all ready on the right track.

However if you just want to make an app that brings people to your website, running javascript I am guessing, this is easy to do with android.

Android supports the webkit browser and has a view group called WebView.  Your app can be nothing more than a shortcut on a desktop that opens a webview directly pointed to your website.  It could add other options to point to other parts of your website like bookmarks.

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
weview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("yoursiteurlgoeshere);
```

A lot of apps on the market are actually based around a WebView.  There are other classes that allow you more control over the view, like whether links are opened in the webview or in a new browser, or whether the user is allowed to use the resize options, etc.

Welcome to Android.

Comment: I would suggest not just creating a webview that points to your website. Why? Because your "app" is then merely a shortcut to your website, which will be hosted in a somewhat gimped (by default) version of the android web browser. You'll get terrible ratings.

What you want to do is add value to your already existing website/service by making it easier to use on android. I know that there are ways that you can make webviews act more like native apps- e.g. respond to multitouch, gestures, etc. Or, you could write a native app that sort of copies the functionality of your website- see facebook.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [massive article](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/03/html5_apps.html) on exactly this type of idea. It discusses a number of different things and is well worth the read if you are indeed interested in making a cross-phone web-app. It talks about an html5 facility in the works for creating such a thing as you describe, but it isn't quite universal yet.

Here is an article on [making an iphone app in html5](http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/html5-iphone-app/).

You can also use [phonegap](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494774/Getting-started-with-Android-PhoneGap-in-Eclipse) to port your design to andorid.

also, check out a jquery plugin calld [jqtouch](http://www.jqtouch.com) if you are interseted in developing touch capable applications quickly.

If you are worried about speed and the issue of internet connectivity, you can use html5 local storage features which are available on both android and itouch. Ibm has a great series on these issues and [part 2 covers local storage](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-html5mobile2/index.html?ca=drs-&ca=dgf-ip).

Answer (score 1):

No. The problem with web technology on a mobile device is the delay. You are far away from the server, so a lot of the things you can easily do with a normal client creates a very bad user experience on a mobile device. The roundtrip time is simply too large. You have to move much more functionality to the client. This client is also less powerfull, and tends to have limits on caching large elements

Comment: Agreed - focus on making the user's experience pleasurable by taking advantage of some of the devices features (storage, etc) to ensure that your app is at least useable should there not be decent signal coverage where the user may be.

Answer (score 0):

> How is this related to C++?

There is also a C++ API which is only recently available. Google calls it the NDK (Native Development Kit). Information about it can be found here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

I personally haven't developed using the NDK. The only real reason someone would really need to would be to write a high-performance application that can't stand the overhead of the Java JVM--which is getting more and more rare these days IMO.

As far as creating a simple app with a web container in it, see Phobos' response. That is exactly how I'd do it personally.